# How to add transition between opened and closed fab?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, floating-action-button

I'm using VueJS and Vuetify. I have added the Vuetify's FAB which opens a list of fabs as shown in the example of the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/floating-action-buttons/#speed-dial):

```
<div id="fab-button">
  <v-speed-dial v-model="fabActiveStatus" bottom left fixed direction="top" transition="slide-y-reverse-transition" style="margin: 25px">
    <template v-slot:activator>
      <v-btn v-model="fabActiveStatus" dark fab x-large :color="fabBgColor">
        <v-icon v-if="fabActiveStatus">mdi-close</v-icon>
        <v-icon v-else>mdi-plus</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-tooltip right>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" fab dark :color="fabBgColor" @click="$emit('fl-btn-settings-popup', true)">
          <v-icon>mdi-upload</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <span>add</span>
    </v-tooltip>
    <v-tooltip right>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" fab dark :color="fabBgColor" @click="$emit('fl-btn-settings-popup', true)">
          <v-icon>mdi-cloud</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <span>goto</span>
    </v-tooltip>
    <v-tooltip right>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" fab dark :color="fabBgColor" @click="$emit('fl-btn-settings-popup', true)">
          <v-icon>mdi-share-variant</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <span>share</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </v-speed-dial>
</div>
```

It works great but I would like to add a transition between opened fab and closed fab. When the fab is closed we have a '+' icon when the fab it opened we have a 'x' icon. I want to add somehow a transition between those two icon like it works in the [vue-fab](https://github.com/PygmySlowLoris/vue-fab):

[image]

As you can see it makes a turn and not just switch between '+' and 'x'. Another example:

[image]

How it can be done using Vuetify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add/remove your own class to the fab icon and give it a spin when open:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    isFabOpen: false,
  })
})
```

```css
#example {
  width: calc(100vw - 6rem);
  height: calc(100vh - 6rem);
  margin: 3rem;
}

div.theme--light.v-application {
  background-color: #f4f6f8;
}

#app .v-speed-dial {
  position: absolute;
}

#app .v-btn--floating {
  position: relative;
}


/*  this is what you want + classes applied on the element */

.rotator {
  transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transform: rotate(0.125turn);
}

.is-rotated {
  transform: rotate(.5turn);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-card id="example" shaped>
      <v-container>
        <v-speed-dial v-model="isFabOpen" :bottom="true" :right="true" :direction="'top'" :transition="'slide-y-reverse-transition'">
          <template v-slot:activator>
            <v-btn
              v-model="isFabOpen"
              :color="isFabOpen ? 'red darken-2' : 'blue darken-2'"
              dark
              fab>
                             <!--  here -->
              <v-icon :class="['rotator', isFabOpen ? 'is-rotated' : '']">
                mdi-close
              </v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-btn fab dark small color="green">
            <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn fab dark small color="indigo">
            <v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn fab dark small color="red">
            <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-speed-dial>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Adjust the rotation by playing with the `rotate()` value. Since the icon has double symmetry, any value of turns ending in `.25`, `.5`, `.75` or `.0` are good for `x` and values ending in `.125`, `.375`, `.625` or `.875` work for `+`.